# What is the black dot beside a jquery sortable element?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-sortable, apotomo

I'm using JQuery sortable for the first time, and I have a sortable list of elements all working ok (widgets, with a header and some internal form etc workings).

I've defined a header element as a handle for moving each widget in the list and that works ok, however a black dot, which behaves like a handle, appears on the left side of each of my sortable elements.

[image]

In some elements, the dot appears when the element starts to move, in others is is permanently fixed

I've Googled around for an hour or so & can find nothing that remotely comes near it

What is this black dot, and how do I remove it?

Comment: The demo at http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ doesn't show a black dot in my browser.  Can you put up a picture?

Comment: pic.twitter.com/rBpwxnmLew - it acts like a handle in that the cursor changes when I hover over it & I can drag the element with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's the bullet of `<li/>`-elements, use similar to the demo linked by Robert Harvey the style

```
list-style-type: none;
```

for the sortable `<ul/>`-element.

Comment: Doh! My mind wasn't thinking <li> it was thinking .sortable. Thanks!